# Explain how basic code is working - Eloquent JavaScript book

Tags: javascript

Here is the code - https://github.com/novaugust/code-wyoming-wiki/blob/master/Day-21.md

here is the info if you want a bigger picture (Eloquent JavaScript by Marijn Haverbeke) - http://eloquentjavascript.net/00_intro.html

I'm new in computer world of programming and I don't understand how simple digits (00110001 etc.) mean 1 + 2 + ... + 10 = 55

I understand

```
var total = 0, count = 1;
while (count <= 10) {
total += count;
count += 1;
}
console.log(total)
```

and

> console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));

but 00110001 00000000 00000000 is not 'magic' for me. Can somebody explain it in a 'simple mode'? BTW is is really embarrassing to stop on page 4...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

Comment: Your binary number actually represents **49**, not 55. From right to left (hey, the same as decimals!): 1 + 16 + 32 = 49.

Comment: Marijn writes "Programs looked something like this" above the binary digits. He did not write that this is the same program. It is just an example.

Comment: Please show the exact code that you are asking about and the results that you are unsure of.

Comment: @Jens Wirth that will explain it. Thanks for all contributors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you're struggling with the concept of binary. This is very common for a lot of people, even life long coders (you don't really need to know it except for hardware stuff).

Essentially binary works identical to the base-10 number system you already know where:
123 = 1 x 100 + 2 x 10 + 3 x 1
OR
123 = 1 x 10^2 + 2 x 10^1 + 3 x 1^0 (^ means exponent)

In binary there are only 2 digits, 0 and 1. However the place-value idea above is the same:

1001:[1 X 2^3] + [0 x 2^2] + [0 x 2^1] + [1 x 2^0]

To determine the value of 1001 you simply perform the calculation above. As a number grows you just increase the number of place values by increasing the exponent power of 2.

Note: 2^n 2^n-1...2^n-n -> formula for a binary number with n+1 digits
      64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 1111111 -> first 7 binary place values

Binary is typically not human-readable, however it posses some cool features that make it easier for us to use. Notably converting binary to hexadecimal(base 16 number system) is a cinch.

It may also help to start small, I found once I was comfortable with what 1111, 1010, 0001 etc. I was more confident with binary as a whole.